# Notification on specific time repeated every day

Tags: java, android, time, notifications, alarmmanager

I want the app to first check something at a specific time (7 AM), and then, if a condition is true, send a notification out, even if the app isn't active or even "only" running in the background.

**This is the code for now (in the `MainActivity.java`):**

```
Intent intent_notification = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , NotificationClass.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent_notification, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);
```

I am not sure about the NotificationClass.class. How does it has to look like in general?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationClass.class` will be Alarm BroadcastReceiver. Alarm service will invoke this receiver on scheduled time.

```
public class NotificationClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //check something at a scheduled time
        if(condition is true){ 
             sendNotification();
        }
    }
}
```

Declare `NotificationClass.class` in your manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationClass"
          android:process=":remote" />
```